# A fast method for computing combination and permutation ratio for a large set in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matlab, combinations

Trying to compute a ratio in a fast efficient method when confronted with a large set of numbers. The idea is an array with numbers example **Box**=[1, 2, 3, 4] and naming name each item in the array to 1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D. then using a number call **step**. Am trying to achieve this for every element in the box, for example in case of the first element A with 3 steps only.

At step 1 take the value of A and divide it by box sum

```
step 1 => 1/10 = 0.1
```

At step 2 take combination BA, CA, DA and divide by box sum subtracting each time by previous value

```
=> (2/10)(1/8) + (3/10)(1/7) + (4/10)(1/6) = 0.1345
```

At step 3 take combination BCA, BDA, CBA, CDA, DBA, DCA and divide by box sum subtracting each time by previous value

```
=> (2/10)(3/8)(1/5) + (2/10)(4/8)(1/4) + (3/10)(2/7)(1/5) + (3/10)(4/7)(1/3) + (4/10)(2/6)(1/4) + (4/10)(3/6)(1/3) = 0.2143
```

and finally return the sum of all the steps for A=0.1 + 0.1345 + 0.2143 = 0.4488
if the same procedural is done to all elements in the box array B= 0.7587 , C= 0.8702, D= 0.9222 to test if calculation was correct the sum of the ratios is equal to 3 the same number of steps used.

If steps and elements in the box are increased it should do all combination in the same order. Can this calculation run fast and not run out of memory if the Box size is 1000 and with 10 steps for every element in the box.

***recurrence formula for an array length 4 with 3 steps***
[A,B,C,D]

for element A

```
step 1 : A
step 2 : BA CA DA
step 3 : BCA  BDA  CBA  CDA  DBA  DCA
```

for element B

```
step 1 : B
step 2 : AB CB DB
step 3 : ACB  ADB  CAB  CDB  DAB  DCB
```

for element C

```
step 1 : C
step 2 : AC BC DC
step 3 : ABC  ADC  BAC  BDC  CAD  CBD
```

for element D

```
step 1 : D
step 2 : AD BD CD
step 3 : ABD  ACD  BAD  BCD  DAC  DBC
```

for an array of 5 elements and 4 steps [A, B, C, D, E]

for element A :

```
   step 1: A

   step 2: BA CA DA EA 

   step 3: BCA BDA BEA CBA CDA CEA DBA DCA DEA EBA ECA EDA

   step 4:   
    BCDA
    BCEA
    BDCA
    BDEA
    BECA
    BEDA
    CBDA
    CBEA
    CDBA
    CDEA
    CEBA
    CEDA
    DBCA
    DBEA
    DCBA
    DCEA
    DEBA
    DECA
    EBCA
    EBDA
    ECBA
    ECDA
    EDBA
    EDCA
```

Here is my try in Matlab code if JS is not possible is there a way to improve the Matlab code instead

```
% sample code to test
userTickets = [1, 2, 3, 4];
users = [0, 0, 0, 0];
userCount = 4;
draws = 3;
for player = 1 :  length(users)
    userLuck = 0;
    for draw = 1 : prizes 
        userLuck = userLuck + cardCombo(player, userTickets, draw);
    end
    users(player) = userLuck;
end
total = sum(users);
```

**** npermutek

```
function [A, I] = npermutek(v,k)
narginchk(2,3);
nck = nchoosek(1:numel(v),k);
permutes = perms(1:k);
I = nck(:,permutes);
I = reshape(I,[],k);
I = sortrows(I,1:k);
A = v(I);
end
```

**** cardCombo

```
function [result] = cardCombo(player, cards, draw)
    playerCards = cards(player);
    opponentCards = cards(setdiff(1:end,player));
    cardCount = sum(cards);
    if draw == 1
        result = playerCards/cardCount; 
    elseif draw == 2
        result = 0;  
        for n = 1 : length(opponentCards)
         result = result + ((opponentCards(n)/cardCount) * (playerCards/ (cardCount - opponentCards(n))));
        end   
    else
        combo = npermutek(opponentCards, draw -1);
        combWithPlayer = repmat(playerCards, size(combo,1),1);
        combo = [combo combWithPlayer];
        rowSize = size(combo, 1);
        colSize = size(combo,2);
        rowSum = 0;
        for row = 1 : rowSize
            rowMul = 1;
            sub = 0;
            for col = 1 : colSize
                num = combo(row, col);
                rowMul = rowMul * (num / (cardCount - sub));
                sub = sub + num;
            end
            rowSum = rowSum + rowMul;
        end
        result = rowSum;
    end    
end
```

Comment: so what was your attempt?

Comment: that looks like a mathematical series disguised as a programming problem. I would suggest you to find which exact series this is before trying to code anything.

Comment: I don't follow the logic for this from your explanation. Your example doesn't make clear why you are doing each step, and one of your intermediate results (0.1345) doesn't seem to be used in the result.

Comment: Not a series, but a probability problem it finds ratios for each item in the array and no mathematical formula for this that I know of. The equation is like so if the values in the box are the number of tickets bought by users in a raffle game and the steps are the number of draws(winners) in the game and every time a user wins all his tickets are removed this calculation would give the probability for every ticket in the box of winning. I tried it in Matlab no attempts in js cant think of a smart way to handle the permutation without multiple loops. sorry fixed the (0.1345)

Comment: Can you please state the recurrence formula? I don't get the example.

Comment: Are the numbers in the box arbitrary or always ascending natural numbers?

Comment: Random natural numbers and the step size always less then the box length  I will add the recurrence formula for a case of box with length 4 and step 3

Comment: OK I think I now understood what you mean by "*box sum subtracting each time by previous value*", but given the order of the letters matters, why did you choose exactly these orders in your combinations? I can't make out a sensible pattern from only three steps.

Comment: Thanks for posting more examples, I think I can now recognise a pattern, but still: don't you have a *formula* or an *algorithm* how you create those? Would be more helpful and make sure we understand what *exactly* you do. Maybe post your matlab code?

Comment: The order is based on the selected index from the box which represents users ticket count lets say box = [2, 3, 6, 7] and am testing to see how much probability the user with 2 tickets has if the game has 3 distinct winners only. step-1 is if the user wins in first draw 1/18 and in step-2 if he wins in second draw so its the product of  another user winning first (3/18)(2/15) + (6/18)(2/12) + (7/18)(2/11). finally if he wins at the 3rd draw and other users winning the first and second step (3/18)(6/15)(2/9) + ...... I will try to add the Matlab code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original method

proba of player P winning at rank exactly `k` is:

```
p(k) = sum_{a={A(k-1, N-1)}}( p(a) * p(P|a) )
```

where

- `N` is the number of players
- `{A(k-1, N-1)}` is the set of all arrangements of `k-1` elem among `N-1`
- `p(a)` the proba of an arrangement from `{A(k-1, N-1)}`

proba g of winning in `[1:k]`

```
g(k) = sum_{i=1}^k p(i)
```

#### Alternative method

An other way: to win either step 1 or ... or step 10 is the opposite of losing in every step

that is...take all arrangements of size k such that no P appear: `A(k, N-1)`

```
g(k) = 1 - sum_{a={A(k, N-1)}} p(a)
```

while shorter formula, the arrangements have a bigger size (k instead of k-1)  so it will take more time... than original method

---

At this point, optimization could be to focus on evaluating the arrangements

we might try an exponentiation:

- compute all `{A(2, N-1)}`
- then `{A(4, N-1)}` by reusing `{A(2, N-1)}` (join them when no two letters in common)
- then concatenate `{A(4, N-1)} x {A(4, N-1)} x {A(2, N-1)}` still with the condition of no two letters in common

But: notice the card of `|{A(4, N-1)}|` is `999*998*997*996 ~= 1e12` (and I don't dare taking such cartesian product)

#### Approximation

Maybe there is better way, but as a fallback, one can simply use a monte carlo approach:

- Make `N` simu
- Draw `k` random numbers. If any number from the draw lands in the `playerInterval`, success
- return `nbSuccess/N`

To avoid resizing an array, consider a `set([1,2,3,...])` and construct virtually the cumulative interval

`]0;1] U ]1;1+2] U ]3;3+3] ... etc`

draw initially from `den == (n*(n+1)/2)`, and check the landing `i-th` interval

If `i !== player`, remove `i` from the set and reconsider the new cumulative interval, redraw from `den-i`
and so forth until `k` (or success)

```js
function A (k, v, cbk) {
  function rec(hand, depth){
    if (depth == k) return cbk(hand)
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
      let x = v[i]
      hand[depth] = x
      v.splice(i, 1)
      rec(hand, depth + 1)
      v.splice(i, 0, x)
    }
  }
  return rec(Array(k), 0)
}
function p (v, den) {
  return v.reduce((acc, num) => {
    acc.res *= num / acc.den
    acc.den -= num
    return acc
  }, { den, res: 1 })
}
//original method
function orig (box, player, steps) {
  const boxWithoutPlayer = box.slice(0)
  boxWithoutPlayer.splice(box.indexOf(player), 1)
  const total = box.reduce((s, x) => s + x, 0)

  let s = player / total
  for (let step = 1; step < steps; ++step) {
    A(step, boxWithoutPlayer, arr => {
      let { den, res } = p(arr, total)
      s += res * p([player], den).res
    })
  }
  return s
}
//alternative method
function neg (box, player, steps) {
  const boxWithoutPlayer = box.slice(0)
  boxWithoutPlayer.splice(box.indexOf(player), 1)
  const total = box.reduce((s, x) => s + x, 0)

  let s = 0
  A(steps, boxWithoutPlayer, arr => {
    s += p(arr, total).res
  })
  return 1 - s
}
//montecarlo approx
function mc (box, player, steps) {
  const NSimu = 1e5
  let success = 0
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
  const getRandomInt = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
  const total = box.reduce((s, x) => s + x, 0)
  for (let i = 0; i < NSimu; ++i) {
    let set = new Set(box)
    let den = total
    for (let s = 0; s < steps; ++s) {
      // n in [1; den]
      const n = getRandomInt(den) + 1
      let idx = 0
      let it = 0
      for(const x of set){
        if (n <= it + x) {
          idx = x
          break
        }
        it += x
      }
      if (idx == player) {
        success++
        break
      }
      den -= idx
      set.delete(idx)
    }
  }
  return success / NSimu
}
function main(box, player, steps, meths) {
  const f = function(key, meth){
    return _=> {
      console.time(key)
      console.log(`player ${player} winning: `,meth(box, player, steps))
      console.timeEnd(key)
    }
  }
  const dic = {
    orig: f('orig', orig),
    neg: f('neg', neg),
    mc: f('mc', mc),
  }
  meths.forEach(m => dic[m]())
  console.log('----')
}
main([...Array(6)].map((x,i) => i + 1), 3, 3, ['orig', 'neg', 'mc'])
main([...Array(10)].map((x,i) => i + 1), 8, 7, ['orig', 'neg', 'mc'])
//takes 1000; 900; 10 about 8s on node on my machine
main([...Array(500)].map((x,i) => i + 1), 250, 10, ['mc'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for showing me the alternative methods. I have not reviewed the code thoroughly yet it will be interesting, but the result of the probability is way off in original method the sum of every user result when added up will not equal the step count. Example Matlab gave for box [3, 7, 10, 4] with 3 steps this [0.543, 0.856, 0.923, 0.675] there sum equal to 3, your method [0.168, 0.337, 0.543, 0.675] their sum 1.726. I don't understand was it suppose to be a quick approximation. Thanks once more for giving up time for us mortals

Comment: I think you miss applied the code. For [3,7,10,4], player 10, calling ```main([3,7,10,4],10,3,['orig', 'neg', 'mc'])``` does give 0.923. The last method (mc) is meant to be quicker but should not be that wrong (in +-0.0x observed)

Comment: You right I was inputting index and not the the value for player...like I said mortals it works great thank you very much for all the help